Why SOCKSv5 client doesn't display length of provided credentials?
I'm building a SOCKS5 Proxy server in node.js, and when I'm using authentication with username and password I'm getting a different reply from the client than what the RFC-1929 defines.
According to the RFC-1929 when the client offers me the authentication methods, and then the server chooses which method should be used. I'm choosing to use the username/password method and the client must return the length of the username, the username itself, the length of the password, and the password itself.
But instead it returns only the username and the password.
The reply should look like this:
       +----+------+----------+------+----------+
       |VER | ULEN |  UNAME   | PLEN |  PASSWD  |
       +----+------+----------+------+----------+
       | 1  |  1   | 1 to 255 |  1   | 1 to 255 |
       +----+------+----------+------+----------+

But instead, it looks like this:
       +----+----------+----------+
       |VER |  UNAME   |  PASSWD  |
       +----+----------+----------+
       | 1  | 1 to 255 | 1 to 255 |
       +----+----------+----------+

So I just simply cannot know what is the username and what is the password because I'm getting both of them as a single string without knowing the length of each of them.
for example when I'm putting username as user and password as pass, and after the whole initial negotiation process I get userpass. now I can't just randomly guess what is the username and what is the passwrod right?
I used the built in macos client. Prefernces > Network > Details > Proxies > SOCKS > etc.
so I thought maybe the clients software is built incorrectly, I downloaded Proxifier and I got the same results. I even observed the initial negotiation process with Wireshark, and even in Wireshark when the client was sending the credentials there was no lengths for them.
Does anybody know why it's not as explained in RFC-1929 standard? and how exactly should I extract the username and the password?

I tried to look again in the Wireshark, and I noticed that the ULEN and the PLEN are not displayed as a separated parameters so it goes like this:
   +----+----------------+----------------+
   |VER | ULEN + UNAME   | PLEN + PASSWD  |
   +----+----------------+----------------+
   | 1  |  1 + 1 to 255  |  1 + 1 to 255  |
   +----+----------------+----------------+

Wireshark Packet Screeshot
